# Navigation and Toolbar customized background image is not working in IOS 5

Tags: iphone

I have implemented customized navigation and toolbar in our project using xcode 4(ios 4.3) and its working fine there but now i have updated my xcode 4.2(ios 5), here its not working. things to be strange please help on this one

Here is my app delegate code

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TopBg_with_logo.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end

@implementation UIToolbar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"btmbar_Bg.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

drawLayer or drawRect method will not be called until you subclass UINavigationBar and call drawRect there.

follow this code -

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx 
{




        if([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]])
        {
            UIImage *image;


            image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_768.png"];



            CGContextClip(ctx);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx,
                               CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage); 


        }
        else 
        {        
            [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];     
        }

}  
@end
```

And add MyNavigationBar.h and MyNavigationBar.m file in your code -

MyNavigationBar.h -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar <UINavigationBarDelegate>

@end
```

MyNavigationBar.m -

```
#import "MyNavigationBar.h"

@implementation MyNavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{



    UIImage *image;

    image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_768.png"];


    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) ];


}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
}


@end
```

And  now subclass your UINavigationBar with MyNavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

in that case use this code:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version >= 5.0) {
        UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"];
        [navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarStyleDefault];   
    }
```